# Is PIX replay using actual driver?

Tags: directx, pix

If I run a 3D application (like a benchmark tool or game) using PIX and replay the capture later, is the replay actually calling the same API (and thus invoking the actual driver and GPU, rather than running a punt back or emulated 3D using CPU) the same way it was when running the original 3D application? I'm focusing only on the Direct3D API part.

Is there any other way I can do the capture, because for some application, PIX fails to capture them.

Is there a way for me to capture only a subset of the rendering, say only the middle 50 frames?